# Accessing REST web service without servlet

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I have a REST web service. Is there any way to create a Rest web service proxy to access the REST web service without using servlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://maxrohde.com/2011/09/02/restlet-quickstart/) you can see the detailed example for Rest without Servlet.

http://maxrohde.com/2011/09/02/restlet-quickstart/

Answer (score 2):

Spring RestTemplate could be another option

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html

Answer (score 2):

Most popular JAX-RS implementation in Java.
Jersey (reference implementation from Oracle)    Apache CXF    RESTeasy    Restlet